# dbt snapshots - backfill

Tags: snapshot, dbt, scd2

We are building a dimension table whose columns do not update very frequently - less than 0.1% of records change on a daily basis. we are thinking about using dbt snapshots. Is dbt snapshot the right strategy? According to the dbt snapshot page, we should avoid using joins. However, this table will have a join and will also involve business logic to calculate some fields. How does backfill work for dbt snapshots?

Initially, we built an incremental table, but that ended up having too many rows. Is dbt snapshot the right strategy?

Comment: That depends on what you want the table for. A snapshot is preferred if you want to know the history of changes in a field (or a set of fields). On the other hand, an incremental model is thought to ease the building time on rather large tables (e.g. instead of building the whole table again and again after each dbt run, just build a defined subset of rows, like the new rows added since the last dbt run).

Comment: Thank you, @AleixCC, for your response. We would like to track changes and keep a history of them. We are currently using the incremental model, which involves copying approximately 60 million rows every day with an upward trend.

Would using a Snapshot be a viable strategy to keep the history? How does the backfill work with dbt Snapshot?

Comment: I'm not aware if that's doable with an incremental strategy, but I am sure that a snapshot is meant exactly for that. You can have a look at the dbt docs for snapshots here, and see if this solution would be appropriate for your use case: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/snapshots

Comment: Keep in mind that the accuracy of a snapshot model is dependent on how often your data changes and how often you run the snapshot job. For example, if you run the snapshot job every hour, and a value for a field changes from VAL1 -> VAL2 -> VAL3 within that 1 hour timespan, you will not have a history of VAL2.